# How to write this equation in LaTeX

Tags: equations

I want the code LaTeX of the following equation.
Can anyone help me?

As shown in my code below, the term (n/r)is not small, 
How I can do it as in the source picture?

source pic:

[image]

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \int_{0}^{1} (f_{n}-{\tiny \frac{n}{r}}   f_{n})^{2} 
 r~dr~+2n\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}f_{n}dr\\
  = \int_{0}^{1}(f_{n}-{\tiny \frac{n}{c}}   f_{n})^{2} r~dr + nf^{n}_{2}(1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TX.SE. There are a lot of resources online that can tell you how to do it. Maybe you can start with https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: I know, but my problem only how to write (n/r) term in a small size!! I tried using \tiny but not working! Can you help me?

Comment: @MohsenAli, try `\frac{n}{r}`.

Comment: I know, but I want it with small size as in the picture above! I used {\tiny \frac{n}[r}} but not working

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In that it would be better if you can specify the exact problem along with the what you have already tried.

Comment: Try `\tfrac` (in my opinion, it's too small).

Comment: Can we showcase this question in some sort of go-to page for "How not to ask a question on tex.se - the perfect example and what specifically is so bad about it"? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\textstyle` at the beginning of each line.  Get rid of `\tiny` (it is a text directive, not a math style).

By default, `$...$` puts the math in `\textstyle`.  However, `\[...\]` as well as `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, and others set the math in the larger `\displaystyle`, by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\textstyle
 \int_{0}^{1} (f_{n}-{\frac{n}{r}}   f_{n})^{2} 
 r~dr~+2n\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}f_{n}dr\\\textstyle
  = \int_{0}^{1}(f_{n}-{\frac{n}{c}}   f_{n})^{2} r~dr + nf^{n}_{2}(1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MohsenAli You are welcome.  And welcome to the site.  Remember, for future reference, that it is important to provide a small minimum working example of code with your questions (beginning with `\documentclass`).

Answer (score 1):

You can have one of these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\textstyle
 \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}(f_{n} - \frac{n}{r} f_{n})^{2}
 r\,dr + 2n \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}f_{n}f_{n}\,dr\\
 \textstyle = \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}(f_{n}- \frac{n}{c} f_{n})^{2} r\,dr + nf^{n}_{2}(1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\!\bigl(f_{n} - \tfrac{n}{r} f_{n}\bigr)^{2}
 r\,dr + 2n \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\!f_{n}f_{n}\,dr\\
  = \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\!\bigl(f_{n}- \tfrac{n}{c} f_{n}\bigr)^{2} r\,dr + nf^{n}_{2}(1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\! \Bigl(f_{n} - \mfrac{n}{r} f_{n}\Bigr)^{\!2}
 r\,dr + 2n \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\!f_{n}f_{n}\,dr\\
  = \prescript{}{0}{\int^{1}}\!\Bigl(f_{n} - \mfrac{n}{c} f_{n}\Bigr)^{\!2} r\,dr + nf^{n}_{2}(1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation]